# Criando um arquivo executável de um programa python em windows 10

Tags: python, windows

Sou usuário do BackBox Linux mas preciso gerar um executável para um programa escrito em Python. Instalei o Windows 10 Pro em VMWare com Python 2.7 e Python 3.4. Utilizo a IDE Pycharm e IDLE. Instalei o pyinstaller através do pip, mas quando tento:

```
pyinstaller -F --clean script.py
```

Recebo o seguinte erro:"failed to create process" Alguma ideia? Como resolver?
Alguma outra maneira de criar um executável?

Comment: Olhando no SO em inglês, parece que é um problema com a instalação do pyinstaller. O que acontece se vc rodar `pyinstaller --version`? Seu sistema de arquivos tem [diretórios com espaços no nome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30620172/pyinstaller-version-failed-to-create-a-process)?

Comment: @hugomg, meu SO está em inglês. Vou fazer o teste e te informo!

Comment: Eu estava falando do StackOverflow.com em inglês, não do sistema operacional hahaha :)

Comment: @hugomg, hahahah. Foi engraçado! Obrigado

Comment: >pip install pyinstall
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyinstall in c:\program files\python36-32\lib\site-packages

Comment: pyinstaller --version
'pyinstaller' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: A segunda mensagem de erro é pq o executável do pyinstaller nao está no seu PATH.

Comment: pyinstaller --version
3.2                                        agora deve funcionar!

Comment: Eu já não gosto muito do Windows... Há alguma maneira de gerar o EXE no Linux?

Comment: Deve dar mas gerar executável de window no Linux sempre é mais chatinho.

Comment: Gerou o EXE mas não rodou no próprio Windows: "the program cant start because msvcr100.dll is missing...

Comment: Uma vez precisei fazer isso para um projeto da faculdade e segui o tutorial desse video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GSoOwSqTSrs Ele explica certinho como fazer pra não ter conflito com as bibliotecas que vc utilizar e tudo mais.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O erro *"the program cant start because msvcr100.dll is missing:"* pode ser resolvido instalando o Microsoft Visual C++.